# Multi Processing in python with reactor

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, twisted

I have a code like this:

```
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor
def Fun1():
    print('No')
communicate1 = task.LoopingCall(Fun1)
communicate1.start(0.1)
reactor.run()

while True:
    print('yes')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Shouldn't it run Func1 and the while loop simultaneously? What's wrong with it? It only prints No.

Comment: Your code as written contains syntax errors (no `def` keyword, `LoopingCall` has not been imported, etc.) Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so that we can provide assistance.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit it

Comment: Ok, now I've edited it, how should I use this reactor for multiprocessing? It won't continue after I call reactor.run

Answer (score 0):

A reactor does multiplexing in a single process and a single thread.  It does not launch multiple threads for you automatically.

`reactor.run()` is expected to run until the entire program shuts down.   No application code comes after that, typically.

Perhaps you want to launch multiple processes, but you'll need to use another library such as `concurrent.futures` or `multiprocessing` or Twisted's [`spawnProcess()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess.spawnProcess.html).

Comment: Note, though, that `concurrent.futures` and `multiprocessing` need to be integrated with Twisted with some care or they will break the reactor.

Comment: I still have the same problem even with multithreading. I think I don't fully understand the threading, it seems as it starts a new thread and lost track of the main one.